# Excel VLOOKUP unexpected result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

How can this cell equal 2 and not 1?

[image: screenshot]

Here's how it should work in my understanding

- D2 has value "Foo"
- It looks for a match in A column
- Finds match in row 4
- Takes column 2 (B) and row 4
- The result is 1

But it doesn't work. Where could be my mistake?

Comment: Use the 4th parameter of VLOOKUP - `0` or `FALSE` - for an exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using an approximate match in the vlookup and not an exact match. Change your formula to:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A2:B10,2,FALSE)
```

To tell excel to look for the lookup value excatly.